# Reference component in another one

Tags: vue.js

In a VueJS file i have two component :

```
var firstComponent = Vue.extend({
     template: '#component1',
     [...]
     methods:
          comp1function: function() {
          [...]
          comp2function()
          }
     [...]
}),
var secondComponent = Vue.extend({
     template: '#component2',
     [...]
     methods:
          comp2function: function(){
               do things here
          }
     [...]
})
```

so what i want to do is to say : do comp2function when you finished to do comp1function. So is there any way i can reference a function from my template component2 in my template component1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Vue Events. I assume you are using VueJS 1.x?

So let's imagine you have those two components as you stated in your question:

```
var firstComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '#component1',
    methods: {
        doSomething () {
            // Do things here
            console.log('I do things')
            // Fire an event when you want:
            this.$dispatch('some-event')
        }
    }
})

var secondComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '#component2',
    methods: {
        doSomethingElse () {
            console.log('I do something else')
        }
    },
    events: {
        trigger () {
            this.doSomethingElse()
        }
    }
})
```

You need to trigger an event from your first component using the `$dispatch` method. Then, in your Vue Instance, you need to get that event, and use `$broadcast` to broadcast a new event to the other Vue children:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        firstComponent,
        secondComponent
    },
    events: {
        'some-event' () {
            this.$broadcast('trigger')
        }
    }
})
```

You will then be able to get the event in your `secondComponent` and trigger whatever method you want

You can learn more about custom events on this page: http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication